# Win32: Accessing a partition beyond the end of a volume?

Tags: c, winapi, disk-partitioning

It's possible to open a disk volume as a file by using a function call like

```
HANDLE hDisk = CreateFile("\\\\.\\G:", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
```

However, that only allows access to the area of the partition occupied by the volume - which may not be all of it.

Is it possible, given the drive letter of the volume, to open a handle to the entire partition? The true size of the partition can be calculated by calling `DeviceIoControl(...IOCTL_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY...)` on the volume handle, but reads/writes beyond the end of the volume do not work.

Comment: This reminds me of the old DOS days when you could use INT13 to access a disk by head/track/sector.

Comment: My suggestion would be to open the whole disk and do the partition recognition yourself.

Comment: you can send `IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER` to volume device stack and get `STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER`. then use `STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER.DeviceNumber` for format \\\\?\\PhysicalDrive%u and open physical device object and use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what appears to be a simpler solution for my use case: the [FSCTL_ALLOW_EXTENDED_DASD_IO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/7d895367-f48f-47db-9ef9-cf20d0ea6782) control code removes the restriction on the volume handle, allowing access to sectors on the partition outside the filesystem. So apart from error checking, it's a one-line addition to my code:

```
DeviceIoControl(hDisk, FSCTL_ALLOW_EXTENDED_DASD_IO, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, &dwBytesRead, NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

exist different device objects for whole disk (fdo) and for partitions (pdo) on it. the first created device for whole disk. it have canonical name format

```
#define FDO_NAME_FORMAT "\\Device\\Harddisk%d\\DR%d"
```

also well known symbolic links created for it

```
"\\Device\\Harddisk%d\\Partition0"
"\\DosDevices\\PhysicalDrive%d"
```

then already, if disk formated and exist partitions on it - created additional volume devices (pdo). the native name of this devices have form

```
"\\Device\\HarddiskVolume%d"
```

and well known symbolic links format for partitions -

```
"\\Device\\HarddiskX\\PartitionY"
```

where `X` the same as for whole disk and `Y` always not 0. so disk device is `\Device\HarddiskX\DRX` or `\Device\HarddiskX\Partition0` or `\DosDevices\PhysicalDriveX` and partitions for on this disk have names `\Device\HarddiskX\PartitionY` (symbolic link to `\Device\HarddiskVolume%d`). when volume is mounted - mount manager can assign letter to device, like `\\\?\c:` but this is only symbolic link to some volume device.

> Is it possible, given the drive letter of the volume, to open a handle
>   to the entire partition?

yes. more correct say handle to entire disk (or partition 0). we can do by send [`IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winioctl/ni-winioctl-ioctl_storage_get_device_number) to volume device and use `DeviceNumber` from [`STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddstor/ns-ntddstor-_storage_device_number) to construct the name of the disk (`"\\\\?\\PhysicalDrive%d"`) on which this partition live. so code can look like

```
ULONG dv(PCWSTR VolumeName)
{
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(VolumeName, 0, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, 0);

    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return GetLastError();
    }

    union {
        STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER sdn;
        DISK_GEOMETRY_EX dg;
    };

    OVERLAPPED ov = {};

    ULONG dwError = DeviceIoControl(hFile, IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER, 0, 0, &sdn, sizeof(sdn), 0, &ov)
        ? NOERROR : GetLastError();

    CloseHandle(hFile);

    if (dwError == NOERROR)
    {
        WCHAR name[32];
        swprintf(name, L"\\\\?\\PhysicalDrive%d", sdn.DeviceNumber);

        hFile = CreateFile(name, FILE_GENERIC_READ, 
            FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, 0);

        if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            if (DeviceIoControl(hFile, IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY_EX, 0, 0, &dg, sizeof(dg), 0, &ov))
            {
                FILE_ALIGNMENT_INFO fai;
                if (GetFileInformationByHandleEx(hFile, FileAlignmentInfo, &fai, sizeof(fai)))
                {
                    if (fai.AlignmentRequirement < 2*sizeof(void*))
                    {
                        fai.AlignmentRequirement = 0;
                    }

                    ULONG_PTR a = fai.AlignmentRequirement;

                    if (PVOID buf = _malloca(dg.Geometry.BytesPerSector + a))
                    {
                        PVOID pv = (PVOID)(((ULONG_PTR)buf + a) & ~a);
                        LARGE_INTEGER ByteOffset;
                        ByteOffset.QuadPart = dg.DiskSize.QuadPart - dg.Geometry.BytesPerSector;
                        ov.Offset = ByteOffset.LowPart;
                        ov.OffsetHigh = ByteOffset.HighPart;
                        ReadFile(hFile, pv, dg.Geometry.BytesPerSector, 0, &ov);
                        _freea(buf);
                    }
                }
            }

            CloseHandle(hFile);
        }
    }

    return dwError;
}
```

here i read the last sector of disk. usual i view here `EFI PART` as first 8  in buffer. on some (removable) flash i view `...NTFS` label